# How to return view with anchor in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller

```
return view('pages.index', compact('errors'));
```

and it works ok but I don't know how to return view to anchor.

```
return view('pages.index#contact', compact('errors'));
```

not works. Error like this appear.

```
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [pages.index#contact] not found.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use some JS. Pass `anchor` variable first:

```
$anchor = 'contact';
return view('pages.index', compact('errors', 'anchor'));
```

Then use `hidden` or something else to pass data to JS:

```
@if (isset($anchor))
    <input type="hidden" name="anchor" value="{{ $anchor }}">
@endif
```

And finally use JS to move the page:

```
$(function () {
    if ( $( "[name='anchor']" ).length ) {
        window.location = '#' + $( "[name='anchor']" ).val();
    }
};
```

It's just an example to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

For That purpose You can Use **Url()** Helper function and route should be defined because **view()** helper function just maps the first argument and fetch that file having .blade extension. In your case it is fetching index.blade.php from page folder. if you will use fragment **#container** with it then it won't be able to find that file. so in that case use **Url(**) helper function.

So you can do:

```
URL::to('/pages/index?contact');
```

In routes.blade.php

```
$route->get("/pages/index?contact","PageController")->with('errors',$errors);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but in Laravel 8 I have been able to do it with **named routes**:

```php
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('home');
})->name('home');
```

Then in a blade template:

```php
<a href="{{route('home')}}#portfolio">Home</a>
```